# Getting records for every year

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle10g

I have two tables named Forms & Attachment.

```
Forms Table
User_Id (PK)  | User_name          | Submitted_date

Attachment table
User_id (FK)  | Attachment_name   | Submitted_date.
```

The Forms can have multiple attachments.

I want write query which will fetch Forms records which do not have attachments for every year since Forms is submitted.
There must be attachment with form for every year since is submitted. I want find records which do not fall in this condition.

Comment: have u tried something..if yes post it

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
SELECT
    f.*
FROM
    Forms f
    left join Attachement a 
        on f.User_id = a.User_id
        and TO_CHAR(f.Submitted_date,'YYYY') = TO_CHAR(a.Submitted_date,'YYYY')
WHERE
    a.Attachement_name IS NULL
```

This will try to join `attachement` with `forms`, so if there is **no attachement** it returns `NULL`, and then **we retrieve only** `NULL` joined attachement.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can think to do this is to populate an ETL style table with PLSQL prior to running the query:

```
create table form_years (user_id number(19), year varchar2(4));

DECLARE
BEGIN
  execute immediate 'TRUNCATE TABLE form_years';
  FOR cur_form IN
  ( SELECT User_Id, TO_CHAR(submitted_date, 'yyyy') AS YEAR FROM Forms
  )
  LOOP
    INSERT INTO form_years
    SELECT cur_form.User_Id,
      TO_CHAR(add_months(to_date('01-01-'
      || cur_form.year,'mm-dd-yyyy'), (rownum -1)*12), 'yyyy')
    FROM all_objects
    WHERE rownum <= (months_between(to_date('01-01-'
      || TO_CHAR(add_months(sysdate, 12), 'yyyy'),'dd-mm-yyyy'),to_date('01-01-'
      || cur_form.year,'mm-dd-yyyy')))/12;
    COMMIT;
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Then query with:

```
SELECT user_id
FROM Forms f
WHERE EXISTS
  (SELECT 0
  FROM form_years
  LEFT OUTER JOIN Attachment
  ON Attachment.user_id     = form_years.user_id
  AND form_years.year       = TO_CHAR(Attachment.Submitted_date, 'yyyy')
  WHERE Attachment.user_id IS NULL
  AND f.user_id             = form_years.user_id
  );
```